How can I call c++ native methods in worklets?
I need a heavy calculating in a worklets function and I write the c++ native methods then call it in worklets, but it says the methods is undefined, please help me write a UI runtime c++ native module, I cannot find anything relate it in the document.
files:
TS part:
import NativeCalcModule from '@root/tm/NativeCalcModule';

export const getPoint = (
  current: number,
  width: number,
  max: number,
  min: number,
  step: number,
  mode: 'round' | 'floor' = 'round',
) => {
  'worklet';

  const res = NativeCalcModule.getPoint(current, width, max, min, step, mode);
  // Error, it says getPoint is undefined but it works in JS thread.

c++ part:
#include "NativeCalcModule.h"

namespace facebook::react
{

    NativeCalcModule::NativeCalcModule(std::shared_ptr<CallInvoker> jsInvoker)
        : NativeCalcModuleCxxSpec(std::move(jsInvoker)) {}

    std::tuple<int, float, float> NativeCalcModule::getPoint(jsi::Runtime &rt, float current, float width, float max, float min, int step, std::string mode)
    {
        if (width <= 0)
        {
            return {0, 0, 0};
        }
 ...

TS interface
export interface Spec extends TurboModule {
  readonly getPoint: (
    current: number,
    width: number,
    max: number,
    min: number,
    step: number,
    mode: 'round' | 'floor',
  ) => Array<number>;
}

export default TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing<Spec>('NativeCalcModule');

